# Trying to transfer data from asynchronous call to another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I understand that it is a stupid question, but i can't find the solution.
 
Here is my code:
ConnectionService.h

```
#import "LaunchScreenViewController.h"
@interface ConnectionService : NSObject

-(void)getsFeaturedProducts;

@end
```

ConnectionService.m

```
-(void)getsFeaturedProducts {
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my-url",[[AppDelegate instance] getUrl]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *getData = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError* error){
        NSString* rawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *value = [rawJson JSONValue];
        _featuredProducts = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:value];
        NSLog(@"Featured products: %@", _featuredProducts);//not empty

        LaunchScreenViewController *lsvc = [[LaunchScreenViewController alloc]init];
        lsvc.featuredProducts = self.featuredProducts;
NSLog(@"Featured products: %@", lsvc.featuredProducts);//not empty
    }];
    [getData resume];
}
```

LaunchScreenViewController.h

```
#import "ConnectionService.h"

@interface LaunchScreenViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary *featuredProducts;
@end
```

LaunchScreenViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    ConnectionService *connectionService = [[ConnectionService alloc]init];
    [connectionService refreshProducts];

    self.featuredProducts = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"featuredProducts: %@", self.featuredProducts);//empty
    NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.featuredProducts allKeys]];
    NSLog(@"All featured product keys: %@", keys);
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

P.S. Programming objective-c less then month, so yeah... thank you for -rep.

Comment: `[[LaunchScreenViewController alloc]init]` creates a new object.  You then update its property but you never present it, so that object's view never appears.  If you already have a `LaunchScreenViewController` on screen, you need to use it instead.

Comment: It was the first what i suggested, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work because the `LaunchScreenViewController` instance created with `alloc init` is not the instance created in the Storyboard / XIB file.

---

The recommended way to retrieve data asynchronously from another class is a completion handler.

In **ConnectionService.m** implement the method with the completion handler and declare it accordingly in the .h file.

```
- (void)getsFeaturedProductsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *products))completion
{
  NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my-url",[[AppDelegate instance] getUrl]];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

  NSURLSessionDataTask *getData = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError* error){
    NSString* rawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *value = [rawJson JSONValue];
    completion(value);
  }];
  [getData resume];
}
```

**Side note: It's strongly recommended to add error handling in the data task !!**

---

In **LaunchScreenViewController.h** declare a property for the `ConnectionService` instance

```
#import "ConnectionService.h"

@interface LaunchScreenViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary *featuredProducts;
@property(nonatomic,strong) ConnectionService *connectionService;
@end
```

---

In **LaunchScreenViewController.m** call the method

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewDidAppear:YES];

  connectionService = [[ConnectionService alloc]init];
  [connectionService getsFeaturedProductsWithCompletion:^(NSDictionary *products) {
    self.featuredProducts = products;
    NSLog(@"featuredProducts: %@", self.featuredProducts);//empty
    NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.featuredProducts allKeys]];
    NSLog(@"All featured product keys: %@", keys);
    connectionService = nil; // release the connectionService instance if needed
  }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about this asynchronous problem wrong - but you're not far off. Here's what your code is doing now:

1. An instance of LaunchScreenViewController is created.
2. That instance of LaunchScreenViewController creates an instance of ConnectionService
3. ConnectionService queries for your asynchronous data
4. When the data is returned, it creates a **BRAND NEW** instance of LaunchScreenViewController and passed it the data.
5. You check the original LaunchScreenViewController for data, but there isn't any - it went to the new instance instead.

*You want to pass the data back to the original LaunchScreenViewController. There are several ways to do that. I'll show you one and link to a second one.*

**Let's do an example on how to pass the data back to the original controller via NSNotificationCenter:**

LaunchScreenViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated{
    //Your current code....

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(receiveConnectionData:) 
    name:@"ConnectionDataReceived"
    object:nil];

}

- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // [notification name] should always be @"ConnectionDataReceived"
    // unless you use this method for observation of other notifications
    // as well.

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"ConnectionDataReceived"]){

        self.featuredProducts = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        NSLog(@"featuredProducts: %@", self.featuredProducts);//empty
        NSArray *
        NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[notification.object allKeys]];
        NSLog(@"All featured product keys: %@", keys);
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
    }
}
```

In your ConnectionService.h

```
-(void)getsFeaturedProducts {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my-url",[[AppDelegate instance] getUrl]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *getData = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError* error){
        NSString* rawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *value = [rawJson JSONValue];
        _featuredProducts = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:value];
        NSLog(@"Featured products: %@", _featuredProducts);//not empty

        //Pass the NSDictionary back to the ORIGINAL LaunchViewController
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  postNotificationName:@"ConnectionDataReceived"  _featuredProducts];
}];
[getData resume];
```

}

NOTE: You can also accomplish this with a Delegate, which is more complex but more robust. You can find a good tutorial on that by Chris Mills here: https://coderchrismills.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/basic-delegate-example/

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result to your controller.

What you need to do is add a completion block to your -(void)getsFeaturedProducts function, then as soon as the result is returned you call it passing back the results.

In the same function you can reload the view using the right data.

**Service**:

```
-(void)getsFeaturedProducts:(void (^)(NSDictionary *featuredProducts))completionHandler {
      NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my-url",[[AppDelegate instance] getUrl]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

      NSURLSessionDataTask *getData = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError* error){
          NSString* rawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          NSDictionary *featuredProducts = [rawJson JSONValue];
          completionHandler(featuredProducts);
      }];
     [getData resume];
}
```

**Controller**:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    ConnectionService *connectionService = [[ConnectionService alloc]init];
    [connectionService refreshProducts:^(NSDictionary *featuredProducts) {
       self.featuredProducts = featuredProducts;
       NSLog(@"featuredProducts: %@", self.featuredProducts);
       NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.featuredProducts allKeys]];
       NSLog(@"All featured product keys: %@", keys);

       //Reload data here...
}];
```

}

Comment: I don't press any controllers, LaunchScreenViewController is the firs ViewController which appear when my app is starting.

Comment: Ill reply... wait  : )

Comment: This answer has the potential to become the most idiomatic and most concise solution. However, @mt81, please add more code. ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)getsFeaturedProducts {
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my-url",[[AppDelegate instance] getUrl]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLSessionDataTask *getData = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError* error){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSString* rawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *value = [rawJson JSONValue];
        _featuredProducts = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:value];
        NSLog(@"Featured products: %@", _featuredProducts);//not empty

        LaunchScreenViewController *lsvc = [[LaunchScreenViewController alloc]init];
        lsvc.featuredProducts = self.featuredProducts;
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:lsvc];
    })

}];
[getData resume];
}
```

Comment: I use storyboard for UI, so i don't use segues. But this `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:lsvc];` don't change anything.

Comment: I want to transfer form `NSObjec` to `ViewController`, not `ViewController->ViewController`